# Trying to get property of 'non-object' - json_decode from API

Tags: php

I am having trouble when trying to use my Livezilla chatbot script to talk to my REST API, both of which I have stored on my local PC. I am using a code snippet very similar from the Livezilla chatbot API page and have modified it, but I am getting some errors.

> 27.02.19 11:34:11 ::1 ERR# 129 Error connecting USER API, invalid response: 
>       http://localhost/livezilla/programytalk.php (
>       Notice:  Trying to get property 'answer' of non-object in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\livezilla\programytalk.php on line 11
>       )  IN LINE 0

the code for programytalk.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$requestobj = json_decode($_POST["livezilla_user_api_request"]);
$responseNode = array();
$responseNode["ResponseTo"] = "";
$responseNode["Id"] = rand(1111111,9999999);
$responseNode["SearchKB"] = false;
$url = "http://localhost:8989/api/rest/v1.0/ask? question=".rawurlencode($requestobj->Value)."&userid=".$requestobj- 
>VisitorId;
$sdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
$responseNode["Value"] = $sdata->answer;
if(!empty($responseNode["Value"]))

            echo json_encode($responseNode);

?>
```

This is the JSON format the API responds in:

```
[{"response":{"answer":"Good morning.","question":"hello world","userid":"1234567890"}},200]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By that API response you don't need to read

```
$responseNode["Value"] = $sdata->answer;
```

instead of that you need to read

```
$responseNode["Value"] = $sdata[0]->response->answer;
```

because answer is nested under response...

Hint: just do this

```
$data = json_decode('[{"response":{"answer":"Good morning.","question":"hello world","userid":"1234567890"}},200]');
print_r($data);
```

and output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [response] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [answer] => Good morning.
                    [question] => hello world
                    [userid] => 1234567890
                )

        )

    [1] => 200
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question in a way that I actually learn from it. However, just having $responseNode["Value"] = $sdata[0]->response->answer; will have to suffice for me as the JSON decode needs to be dynamic based on what the user has inputted so the BOT returns the correct answer in JSON. Thank you for your help

Comment: np, my suggestion for you is to always print_r on object or array before you use it because that is the simplest way to find out what is nested under what...

Answer (score -3):

Please do this;

```
<?php
$requestobj = json_decode($_POST["livezilla_user_api_request"]);
$responseNode = array();
$responseNode["ResponseTo"] = "";
$responseNode["Id"] = rand(1111111,9999999);
$responseNode["SearchKB"] = false;
$url = "http://localhost:8989/api/rest/v1.0/ask? question=".rawurlencode($requestobj->Value)."&userid=".$requestobj- 
>VisitorId;
$sdata = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$responseNode["Value"] = $sdata->answer;
if(!empty($responseNode["Value"]))

            echo json_encode($responseNode, true);

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___do this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: `true` is a parameter for a `json_decode()` NOT a `json_encode()`